# cURL Commands in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Hi there so i am trying to use the Freenom API for a service called iForce to register domain names for people really easily and i came accross this cURL command but i have no idea how to make PHP run it.

The following is the command

```
 curl -X GET "https://api.freenom.com/v2/domain/search.xml\
    ?domainname=test001.tk\
    &email=john@smith.net\
    &password=68bb651cb1\
    &domaintype=PAID"
```

If someone could please convert that to php or tell me how to or tell me how to use it in php that would be amazing!

Thank you so so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Curl with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899037/executing-curl-with-php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.freenom.com/v2/domain/search.xml?domainname=test001.tk&email=john@smith.net&password=68bb651cb1&domaintype=PAID");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Try it on true first, if that fails, set it back to false.

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Now you can use `$server_output` for your needs.

Comment: You should NOT turn off peer verification unless you absolutely know what you're doing. In most cases you don't.

Comment: True, the only reason I added it, is cause most open API's on HTTPS protocol, will return a failed request if verification is `true`. I don't know why.

Comment: That's likely because you're running on localhost, or on a server that [do not have certificates properly set up](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/). The correct solution is to fix the certificates—not turn off certificate verification.